# How can I get VLC 2.2+ on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: vlc

I have tried adding other repositories via apt that backport vlc but when I do

```
apt-get install vlc
```

I still get VLC 2.0.8

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information found on [VideoLan.org](http://videolan.org):

> "Ubuntu includes whichever VLC version was the latest at the time the
>   Ubuntu release was frozen (typically about two months before the
>   official Ubuntu upgrade). Afterward, you can still get security and
>   critical bug fixes, but no further major VLC version updates until the
>   next Ubuntu release."

The very latest stable prior to the freeze is 2.0.8.  You can however get 2.1.2 from a third party PPA.  Information can be found at [UbuntuHandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-vlc-2-1-2-ubuntu-12-04/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I would recommend upgrading to 14.04 as the only updates you will see on VLC are security updates.  If you are running crouton on a Chromebook, options are available for newer releases, you just need to provide the release information at install or modify the chroot accordingly.

Comment: This third party ppa is no longer active.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
apt-get update
apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: @user11960 The PPA which is located at [https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily) is still active, but only contains version 2.0.8 for Ubuntu 12.0

Comment: Sorry. That comment was meant for @kyodake's answer.

Comment: this will also give vlc 2.0.8 see https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily?field.series_filter=precise